# Python os.walk complex directory criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, include, os.walk

I need to scan a directory with hundreds or GB of data which has structured parts (which I want to scan) and non-structured parts (which I don't want to scan).

Reading up on the os.walk function, I see that I can use a set of criteria in a set to exclude or include certain directory names or patterns.

For this particular scan I would need to add specific include/exclude criteria per level in a directory, for example:

In a root directory, imagine there are two useful directories, 'Dir A' and 'Dir B' and a non-useful trash directory 'Trash'. In Dir A there are two useful sub directories 'Subdir A1' and 'Subdir A2' and a non useful 'SubdirA Trash' directory, then in Dir B there are two useful subdirectories Subdir B1 and Subdir B2 plus a non useful 'SubdirB Trash' subdirectory. Would look something like this:

[image: Example Directory]

I need to have a specific criteria list for each level, something like this:

> level1DirectoryCriteria = set("Dir A","Dir B")
>
> level2DirectoryCriteria = set("Subdir A1","Subdir A2","Subdir
>   B1","Subdir B2")

the only ways I can think to do this are quite obviously non-pythonic using complex and lengthy code with a lot of variables and a high risk of instability. Does anyone have any ideas for how to resolve this problem? If successful it could save the codes running time several hours at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
to_scan = {'set', 'of', 'good', 'directories'}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d in to_scan]
    #whatever you wanted to do in this directory
```

This solution is simple, and fails if you want to scan directories with a certain name if they appear in one directory and not another.  Another option would be a dictionary that maps directory names to lists or sets of whitelisted or blacklisted directories.

Edit: We can use `dirpath.count(os.path.sep)` to determine depth.

```
root_depth = root.count(os.path.sep) #subtract this from all depths to normalize root to 0
sets_by_level = [{'root', 'level'}, {'one', 'deep'}]
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    depth = dirpath.count(os.path.sep) - root_depth
    dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d in sets_by_level[depth]]
    #process this directory
```

Comment: This looks promising- I'm trying it out and will come back to you.

Comment: The solution came from this!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer concerning `os.walk` but just a suggestion: Since you're scanning the directories anyways, and you obviously know the trash directories from the other directories, you could also place a dummy file in the trash directories `skip_this_dir` or something. When you iterate over directories and create the file list, you check for the presence of the `skip_this_dir` file, something like `if 'skip_this_dir' in filenames: continue;` and continue to the next iteration.

This may not involve using `os.walk` parameters, but it does make the programming task a little easier to manage, without the requirement of writing a lot of 'messy' code with tons of conditionals and lists of include/excludes. It also makes the script easier to reuse since you don't need to change any code, you just place the dummy file in the directories you need to skip.

Comment: Its  a good idea but it could take a long time to add a skip flag to the dirs I don't want to scan. It's much easier to say which dirs I do want to scan and if in the future I need to add some, it's relatively easy. You're right about avoiding the complicated code though - I will bear your suggestion in mind.

Comment: Yeah, if you have lots of trash directories it could be cumbersome to flag them all. You could also turn the reasoning around by flagging the dirs you do want to process, but I assume you probably also have a great number of directories you do need to process.

Answer (score 0):

By using the root.count(os.path.sep) I was able to create specific instructions on what to include/exclude on each level in the structure. Looks something like this:

```
import os

root_depth = root.count(os.path.sep) #subtract this from all depths to normalize root to 0

directoriesToIncludedByLevel = [{"criteriaString","criteriaString","criteriaString","criteriaString"},#Level 0
                               {"criteriaString","criteriaString","criteriaString" },#Level 1
                               {},#Level 2
                               ] 

directoriesToExcludedByLevel = [{}, #Level 0
                               {},  #Level 1
                               {"criteriaString"},  #Level 2
                                ]


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):

    depth = dirpath.count(os.path.sep) - root_depth

    # Here we create the dirnames path depending on whether we use the directoriesToIncludedByLevel or the directoriesToExcludedByLevel
    if depth == 2: #Where we define which directories to exclude
        dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d not in directoriesToExcludedByLevel[depth]]
    elif depth < 2 :  #Where we define which directories to INclude
        dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if d in directoriesToIncludedByLevel[depth]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution similar to OP. I needed to scan the subfolders and needed to exclude any folder that had folders labeled 'trash'.
My solution was to use the string find() method. Here's how I used it:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(your_path):
    if dirpath.find('trash') > 0:  
        pass
    elif dirpath.find('trash)') < 0:
        do_stuff
```

If 'trash' is found, then it will return the index number. Otherwise find() will return -1.

You can find more information on the find() method here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm